# How to choose pixel value for NoData when clipping satellite imagery?

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, clip, sentinel-2

I downloaded a Sentinel 2A image because I want to obtain different index for land usage. I need to clip every band of the satellite imagery using the [Clip Multi Layers plug in](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ClipMultipleLayers/). The plug-in defaults to a value of -999 for NoData cells.

What is the NoData pixel value I should use to clip the imagery so as not to interfere with pixel data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please DO NOT USE ALL CAPS in your titles.

Comment: Which Sentinel-2 product? MSI L1C or L2A? What do you want to achieve exactly? Nodata value of most S2 products is 0. This is properly declared in the JP2 files and most GIS programs can handle this.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Is Sentinel-2 L1C, so I doing a land cover classification of a state of Mexico, but this is an irregular polygon so I have decided to make a clip from the bands that I need, but I have the doubt  if this value can make noise at the time that run the classification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice is up to you, but try to ensure that whatever value you use gets into the metadata of the output format you save. That will ensure that other software will recognise it by default.

I tend to use -9999, and -999 is a good one too. A bad value to use is one that is actually found in your dataset! (Sounds obvious, but it's sometimes done.)

Comment: Usefull! and sounds logical, so if I use "0", what do you think ?

Comment: "0" is ok, so long as you don't have any real values near 0! It should be recognisable as a ridiculous value, or fit into what others do.